# Android Game Development: Framerate & Collisions

Tags: android, collision-detection, frame-rate

I've created a simple collision detection script, which works this way:
When the distance between the hero and an object is x pixels, the hero can "walk" x pixels, when he would not collide with an object (hero + 3px = no collision) he moves by 5 pixels.
But I also have to consider the framerate and therefor multiply his speed with the elapsed time /20
My problem is, when the framerate at some time is very low or high, he just moves by an additional pixel (1px) ..the chance is very small, but it still can happen.
so what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: is this detection by a thread? What happens if your frame rate is at maximum and minimum?

Comment: elapsed time /20 or  elapsed time /20.0f or  elapsed time /20.0d ?

Comment: the detection-script is called everytime the hero moves and the thread calls checkAction(), which checks for buttons being pushed.

its /20f

Comment: elapsed time in milliseconds ?

Comment: yep, the output is mostly: elapsedTime = 15; elapsedTime /20f = 0,75

Comment: low framerate would give something like 300ms-->300/20f=15.0 when you multiply this with speed, what do you get?

Comment: I've got about 67 frames/sec all the time and if I would multiply 15 with the speed, it would be 75px instaed of 5px..so my collision detection script would be useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a position correction to the end of post-collision-check or add a velocity correction to the end of pre-collision-check.

Post-collision: object is translated back to the collision point.

Pre-collision: object speed is altered temporarily so in the next frame it will be on the point of collision.

Example:

- Your object moves 75 pixels and tunnells through the wall. What to
  do? You need a position history of 1-iteration-back. Looking to
  history, you see it was actually behind the wall, then the current
  location-->it is now passed the wall xx pixels. Then you would set
  its new position next to wall `before` painting.
- You cannot know when it will lag your android: better algortihm needed to make it independent of fps. How? you may just pause whole world a bit until fps is steady again or just store the next few iteration before painting then calculate things before painting.

Comment: I already the pre-collsion-check, but I'll consider the post-collsion-check! thank you :)